# Filling in the textboxes with data from database in C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms

How to fill in the textboxes with the data from data base once clicked on the Data grid view column in C#?

If i click on the whole row in datagridview, I want the data to be put into the textboxes on window form design.

Answer (score 0):

I use a two step process the first step I have data loaded in a DataGridView
Click on it to get the ID of the person I want to display the data in textbox's
Here is the click event for the DataGridView

```
       private void dgvPerson_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 | e.ColumnIndex == -1)
        {
            tbMessage.Text = "No Clicking Here";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

            Close();
            frmADE fADE = new frmADE();
            udID = ID;
            if (doWhat == 2)
            {
                fADE.doWhat = 2;
            }
            if (doWhat == 3)
            {
                fADE.doWhat = 3;
            }
            if (doWhat == 4)
            {
                fADE.doWhat = 4;
            }
            var form = new frmCRUD();
            form.GetID(udID);
            fADE.Show();
        }
    }
```

OK now I have the ID it is in the variable newData and I read the data
In my case the Database CRUD functions are in a Class Library
Just change all those fn,ln,ad variables to the names of your TextBox's

```
        public void readUDV()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM FriendsData WHERE FID = " + newData, conn))
            {
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        fn = rdr["fxFirstName"].ToString().Trim();
                        ln = rdr["fxLastName"].ToString().Trim();
                        ad = rdr["fxAddress"].ToString().Trim();
                        ct = rdr["fxCity"].ToString().Trim();
                        st = rdr["fxState"].ToString().Trim();
                        zp = rdr["fxZip"].ToString().Trim();
                        ph = rdr["fxCellPhone"].ToString().Trim();
                        em = rdr["fxEmail"].ToString().Trim();
                        rt = rdr["fxInfo"].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```